# local socket = require("socket"), module 'socket' not found

Tags: c++, sockets, dll, lua

Im using Lua with C++ in a project in Visual Studio 2015. I have used Luarocks to create socket/core.dll and mime/core.dll. I have added the core.dll to the debug folder where my C++ program executes. The error I get in lua is generated when "require("socket")" executes. The following error is what I get:

```
...s\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\Client.lua:17: module 
'socket' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket']
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio         
2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\lua\socket.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\lua\socket\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\socket.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\socket\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\..\share\lua\5.3\socket.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\..\share\lua\5.3\socket\init.lua'
    no file '.\socket.lua'
    no file '.\socket\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\socket.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\..\lib\lua\5.3\socket.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RaceGame3\Debug\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\socket.dll'
```

So to sum up: How do I correctly link the core.dll or other luasocket files to my current Lua instance while running the C++ project?

Comment: when I look at the luasocket source "makefile" it says that it targets version 5.1 and 5.2 but I am using version 5.3...

also I read on the internet that I may need to "statically link" luasocket but Im not sure how

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar issue by changing the `require` to:

```
require("socket.core")
```

That only works, of course, if you have the `core.dll` inside a folder named `socket` that can be found locally or in your `PATH` / `package.cpath`, etc..

You could also rename `core.dll` to `socket.dll` (and place it in a searchable folder).

The problem, as far as I know, is: the required name and the actual dll name simply doesn't match.

**edit:** To play safe, I've put the lua modules and the dll together, locally, like this:

```
socket
├── core.dll
├── ltn12.lua
├── mime.lua
├── mime-1.0.3.dll
├── socket
│   ├── ftp.lua
│   ├── headers.lua
│   ├── http.lua
│   ├── smtp.lua
│   ├── tp.lua
│   └── url.lua
└── socket.lua
```

Comment: I put the core.dll in folder /libs/socket/core.dll
after I did so and changed lua code to "local socket = require("libs.socket.core")"

I got another error which translated to english becomes "the given module cant be found", if I changed the name of the .dll file to socket.dll the ordinary paths error showed up just like before

Comment: "The specified module could not be found", so it find the .dll but it cannot load it

Comment: On my setup the dll and the lua files are packed together, exactly because luasocket was giving me trouble finding stuff. I've edited the answer to show how  I'm keeping my dll/lua files.

Comment: I have implemented the same setup as you have in your solution. Lua seems to find the .DLL, it does not complain about any paths in the error message. However the error "The specified module could not be found" is being displayed.

Comment: That's unfortunate.
My builds are plain simple with makefiles and no specific build folders (release, debug, etc.), so I've managed to isolate the problem and fix it as I've told above.
Maybe someone more familiar with VS will be able to help you then...
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You were in a very similar situation to me. In my case, I required `socket.http` in sample.lua,

```
require("socket.http")
content, status, header = socket.http.request("http://website.com/aaa.php")
```

and have met the following error message:

```
...\MyProject\Release\sample.lua:1: module 'socket.http' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.http']
    no file '.\socket\http.lua'
    (...)
```

I've addressed this issue by putting some necessary lua scripts and dll files in the path where a sample executable is located.

```
Release
├── socket
│   ├── ftp.lua
│   ├── http.lua
│   ├── smtp.lua
│   ├── tp.lua
│   └── url.lua
├── mime
│   └── core.dll
├── ltn12.lua
├── mime.lua
├── socket.dll    <--- renamed from $(LUA_PATH)\clibs\socket\core.dll
├── socket.lua
├── lua5.1.dll
├── sample.exe
└── sample.lua
```

The cpp code is as follows:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "lua5.1.lib")
#include <lua.hpp>
void main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "sample.lua");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Comment: `sample.exe` and `sample.lua` has given a hint how this answer could help